# Как получить определённые данные из toLocaleString?

Tags: javascript, html5

У меня такой вопрос. Как получить данные из [toLocaleString()?](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)

Примерь из этой кода:

```
         let date = new Date();
         let options = {
            hour: "numeric",
            minute: "numeric", 
            second: "numeric",
            timeZoneName: "short",
            weekday: "long",
            year: 'numeric',
            month: "long", 
            day: "numeric"
        };


  console.log(date.toLocaleString('ru', options));
```

как получить `hour`, `minute`, `second`, `month`?
и сохранить в переменную. 
Я знаю это можно сделать так:

```
let hours = date.getHours();
let minutes = date.getMinutes();
let seconds = date.getSeconds();
let month = date.getMonth();
```

Но это нехороший вариант..

Можно каким-то образам их получить и сохранить в переменную? 
Есть какой-то способ сделать это, примерно похоже этого date.toLocaleString.month 
Для чего это нужно?

1) Чтобы исправить такую ошибку. `1:3:24`
 
2) Чтобы потом использовать.. Ну пример для часа в сайте.
3) Чтобы сокращать количество кода. Пример: если мы используем простой `date.get` тогда чтобы получить месяц в текстовым порядке надо еще несколько строк кода писать.

Думаю, ответ для многих будет полезным.

Мне еще примерное использования тоже добавить?
P.S. Все это будет при сходить внутри функции. И как использовать полученный результат в другом месте? С помощью  `return`?

Comment: А где вы нашли, что можно передать первым параметром `ru` в функцию `toLocaleString`?

Comment: Читал 
 <a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString"> тут </a> 
 и <a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl#Locale_identification_and_negotiation"> тут </a><br>
 и понял что, в этом коде:
 dateObj.toLocaleString([locales[, options]]) <br>
качество параметре locales можно указать регион/язык/локация и попробовал(для en ko 
 остальных тоже работает))). Работает как нужно...

Comment: Гмм.. Ну ладно. Вы хотите получить из строчки значение часа, минуты и секунды? Но ведь `date.getHours();` гораздо удобнее и надежнее, чем парсить строчку.

Comment: Да можно, как я указал в вопросе . Но, как получить остальные элементы?пример: мне надо брать имя месяца. А  это сделать  в date.getMonth() не удобно.  А в toLocaleString это сделать удобно и можно настроить дату зависимого от пользователя. Исправил вопрос.

Comment: @Alex указал в вопросе.,

Comment: @Alex да. Точнее хочу получить их  и сохранить в переменный. Пример: результат выше указанного кода, будет так: вторник, 30 октября 2018г., 16:48:18 GMT. //Это зависит от времени пользователя. Ну примерно так, мне надо получить тут часы, секунду, минуту, месяц в переменный. Чтобы потом их использовать.

Comment: Нет, так не делается, это очень неудобно. Неудобно парсить строчку, что бы вытащить оттуда название месяца (например). Если вы в будущем поменяете локаль, и заходите вытаскивать название месяца на английском, то вам придется снова писать код для парсинга строки. Если вы хотите плотно работать с датами, могу посоветовать `moment.js`.

Comment: Мне это удобное был чем date.get (Если знал бы как получить). Я думал есть какой-то способ сделать это, примерно похоже этого date.toLocaleString.month. Про локаль не думал.. А вот moment.js это другое дело.. Там почти есть  то что мне нужно(немного видел результаты). Надо разобраться.. Эх теперь не удобно.. Чтобы работать с датами надо выучить целую библиотеку..

Comment: Встроенного такого средства в js нету. Можете посмотреть библиотеки `moment.js` или `sugar.js`. Обе делают то, что вы хотите, и даже больше!

Comment: Да, видел(читал) с их помощью можно делать многое с датами..))